# centos 7 pip install cx_oracle. error: cannot locate oracle instant client sdk rpm header files

Tags: linux, oracle, centos, cx-oracle

after install oracle-instantclient11.1-basic-11.1.0.7.0-1.x86_64.rpm

centos 7 pip install cx_oracle. error:

```
setup.py,line 144,in FindInstantClientRPMInclude
raise DistutilsSetupError("cannot locate Oracle Instant Client")
distutils.errors.DistutilsSetupError: 
cannot locate oracle instant client sdk rpm header files
```

why?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to set any environment variables. But you do need to ensure that the instantclient-devel package is also installed!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set an environment variable
(of course, **use the correct path for your system**)

First try

```
export LD_RUN_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1
```

If that doesn't work try

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1
```